# Conditionally use tmpfs mount for Docker RUN step

Tags: docker

Docker supports the following syntax for mounting a `tmpfs` at a particular path while performing a `RUN` step as part of a container image build:

```
RUN --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/build cd /build && cmake /src && cmake --build .
```

See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypetmpfs

If I'm building on a system with too little memory, this might cause an issue. Can I conditionally disable the use of `tmpfs` mount?

It does *not* work to pass it as a build argument:

```
ARG TMPFS_MOUNTS=--mount=type=tmpfs,target=/build
RUN $TMPFS_MOUNTS ls

 > [2/2] RUN --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/build ls:
#5 0.168 /bin/sh: 1: --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/build: not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to mount the tmpfs unconditionally, but *use* it conditionally by creating a symlink depending on the value of a build argument.

```
ARG USE_TMPFS=true
RUN --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/tmpfs \
    ([ "$USE_TMPFS" = "true" ] && \
      ln -s /tmpfs /build || \
      mkdir /build) && \
    cd /build && cmake /src && cmake --build .
```

I could not get a bind mount to work.